# What is the most affordable way to send/receive text messages from a Ruby on Rails web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms

Title kind of says it all. I've being doing extensive research but having a hard time finding a cost effective answer. I'm creating a RoR application that requires texts to be sent out occasionally to a customer and for that customer to be able to reply, where my application could then put that reply into a database for further processing. Does anyone have experience with this that may be able to help? Thank you.

Comment: Which companies have you looked into so far? What about those companies have you been unhappy with? What do you consider cost-effective?